# JavaFX: detect when Node is rendered

Tags: java, events, javafx, netbeans, render

How can I detect when a Node is rendered?

I tried with this code in the controller:

```
private boolean isRendered = false;

@Override
protected void layoutChildren() {
    super.layoutChildren();
    if(!isRendered){
        do_something();
    }
    isRendered = true;
}
```

And it works quite good, but there is a bit of lag between `do_something()` is called and the moment when all the nodes are shown on the screen.

There is an event fired when all the node are really rendered on the screen?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  You just want to draw on top of a Node?

Comment: I have a loading screen that I would close when all graphic is rendered.

Comment: There is a event for when all the nodes are ***layouted***, but only in javafx 9+, see [`Scene.addPostLayoutPulseListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#addPostLayoutPulseListener-java.lang.Runnable-)

Comment: How long do your graphics need to render?  Even a ten-year-old machine can render a full screen in a fraction of a second.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I don't know what `do_something()` is doing, but perhaps what you really want to do is `do_something()` in a [concurrent task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm) so that you don't block the JavaFX thread.  Like this [splash screen implementation](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2305098), for example.

Comment: I think that @fabian solution is that I need, because I need to know when all scene is rendered every time it changes.

@jewelsea, that not the point: `do_something()` create another thread, but anyways there is a little lag of about second (maybe less) between creation of the thread and effective rendering.